# set and refer to variables in yaml

Tags: azure-devops, yaml

I have the following yml code that sets and refers to some variables as follows:

```
<one.yml>
- task: AzurePowerShell@4
  displayName: 'Copy functions templates'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{parameters.serviceConnection}}
    ScriptPath: ${{ parameters.root }}/Scripts/ReleaseManagement/CopyChildTemplatesToContainer.ps1
    ScriptArguments: '-resourceGroupName ''${{ parameters.solutionAbbreviation}}-data-${{ parameters.environmentAbbreviation}}'' 
  name: copyFunctionsTemplates

- powershell: |
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=data_containerSASToken;isOutput=true]$(copyFunctionsTemplates.containerSASToken)"
    Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=data_containerEndPoint;isOutput=true]$(copyFunctionsTemplates.containerEndPoint)"
  displayName: 'set data output variables'
  name: dataVariables
  
 <two.yml>
 
  stages:
  - deployment: ${{ parameters.stageName }}_DeployResources
    displayName: ${{ parameters.stageName }}_DeployResources
  - stage: ${{ parameters.stageName }}
    dependsOn: ${{ parameters.dependsOn }}
    condition: ${{ parameters.condition }}
    
    jobs:
    - deployment: ${{ parameters.stageName }}_DeployResources
      displayName: ${{ parameters.stageName }}_DeployResources
       steps:
       - template: one.yml
               
    jobs:
    - job: ${{ parameters.stageName }}_DeployFunctions
      dependsOn: ${{ parameters.stageName }}_DeployResources
      variables:
        data_containerEndPoint: $[ dependencies.DeployResources.outputs['DeployResources.dataVariables.data_containerEndPoint'] ]
        data_containerSASToken: $[ dependencies.DeployResources.outputs['DeployResources.dataVariables.data_containerSASToken'] ]       
      steps:       
        - ${{ each func in parameters.functionApps }}:
          - template: three.yml              
              
              
<three.yml>           

steps:

- task: AzureResourceGroupDeployment@2
  displayName: 'deploy ${{ parameters.name }} data resources'
  inputs:
    azureSubscription: ${{parameters.serviceConnection}}
    resourceGroupName: ${{parameters.solutionAbbreviation}}-data-${{parameters.environmentAbbreviation}}
    location: ${{parameters.location}}
    csmFile: ${{ parameters.root }}/functions_arm_templates/${{ parameters.name }}/Infrastructure/data/template.json
    csmParametersFile: ${{ parameters.root }}/functions_arm_templates/${{ parameters.name }}/Infrastructure/data/parameters/parameters.${{parameters.environmentAbbreviation}}.json
    overrideParameters: -environmentAbbreviation "${{parameters.environmentAbbreviation}}" 
                        -tenantId "${{parameters.tenantId}}"
                        -solutionAbbreviation "${{parameters.solutionAbbreviation}}" 
                        -containerBaseUrl "$(data_containerEndPoint)functions/${{ parameters.name }}/Infrastructure/data/" 
                        -containerSasToken "$(data_containerSASToken)"
    deploymentMode: 'Incremental'
```

On enabling the debug mode while running pipeline, I see values printed for data_containerSASToken and data_containerEndPoint from the task 'Copy functions templates' however I see empty values from the task 'deploy data resources'. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem may be in when you retrieve the output from the previous job:

```
data_containerEndPoint: $[ dependencies.DeployResources.outputs['DeployResources.dataVariables.data_containerEndPoint'] ]
```

That's looking for a prior job called `DeployResources`, but the prior job is actually called `{{ parameters.stageName }}_DeployResources`.